Se requiere una referencia no estáticos a la hora de crear un object pool en Unity
Estoy teniendo el problema : Se requiere una referencia de objeto para el campo, método o propiedad 'ObjectPool.CreateInstance(PoolableObject, int)' no estáticos.
public class EnemySpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player;
    public int numberOfEnemiesToSpawn = 1;
    public float spawnDelay = 1f;
    public List<EnemyScript> enemyPrefabs = new List<EnemyScript>();

    private Dictionary<int, ObjectPool> _enemyObjectPools = new Dictionary<int, ObjectPool>();

    private void Awake()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < enemyPrefabs.Count; i++)
        {
            // Aquí da el error
            _enemyObjectPools.Add(i, ObjectPool.CreateInstance(enemyPrefabs[i], numberOfEnemiesToSpawn));


        }
    }

El tema es que la clase que estoy usando, ObjectPool, es pública, tiene el constructor al que estoy llamando y no es estático:
    public ObjectPool CreateInstance(PoolableObject prefab, int Size)
    {
        ObjectPool pool = new ObjectPool(prefab, Size);

        GameObject poolObject = new GameObject(prefab.name + " pool");
        pool.CreateObjects(poolObject.transform, Size);

        return pool;
    }

